# I have to convert jpg file to YUV422 planar format by using ffmpeg

Tags: linux

I have to display the some Images on the video clip like a watermark. It is needed to convert from jpg to YUV422 Planar format.
Could you someone explain to convert this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Try it

```
ffmpeg -i a.jpg -s 640x480 -pix_fmt yuv422p a.yuv
```

To back from yuv422p to jpg

```
ffmpeg -pix_fmt yuv422p -s 640x480 -i a.yuv b.jpg
```

Comment: Thanks Alexcei, Is it possible to separate Y and UV flie?

Comment: Thanks Alexcei, Is it possible to separate Y and UV flie? Do you know how i separate from YUV to Y and UV file.

Comment: oh, I don't know it